# How to remove "zeroes" in parallel from two lists in Python?

Tags: python

I am faced with a problem that obviously can be solved with a series of loops and conditional statements, but I was wondering if there was a particularly simple and elegant way to do this with Python.

Basically I have two lists of integers of the same length. Some values ​​can be zero. I would like to get two more lists in which, not only the null elements are missing but also those element that are null in the other list are removed.

For example, if I have

```
l1 = [0, 1, 3, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]
l2 = [4, 7, 0, 0, 8, 9, 1, 2]
```

I would like to get

```
nz1 = [1, 6, 8]
nz2 = [7, 8, 1]
```

Clearly there are many ways to do this in Python, but which is the most elegant? Since the lists are short I don't care about the fastest way. Speed is not important. I am looking for good readable code. Possibly using the standard Python libraries, not additional ones, as `numpy`.

Answer (score 7):

```py
out1, out2 = zip(*filter(all, zip(l1, l2)))

> out1
(1, 6, 8)

> out2
(7, 8, 1)
```

This one-liner is relatively efficient as it uses generators, but it returns tuples, you could convert these to lists afterwards if you really need to:

```py
> list(out1)
[1, 6, 8]
```

The idea here is that we use `zip` to iterate over pairs of values from the two parallel lists. This gives us a stream of pairs. We then use `filter` to drop values from the stream - the `all` function will return `False` if any values in the pair are 'falsy' i.e. when one or both values are `0`. Lastly we use the `zip(*<sequence>)` trick to 'unzip' our filtered zip stream back into two separate sequences.

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Comment: `filter(all, zip(..))`…!

Comment: @deceze nice, I'll update with that

Comment: You can also wrap the zip inside map(list, ...) to destuct out1 and out2 of list type.

Answer (score 1):

That is a nice problem to solve. You can actually `zip` two more lists and it will give you a tuple of each element

```
l1 = [0, 1, 3, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]
l2 = [4, 7, 0, 0, 8, 9, 1, 2]

nz1 = []
nz2 = []
for x, y in zip(l1, l2):
  if x != 0 and y != 0:
    nz1.append(x)
    nz2.append(y)

print(nz1)
print(nz2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 6, 8]
[7, 8, 1]
```

Update: Just in case anyone wants to get a one-liner

```
nz1, nz2 = map(list, zip(*filter(all, zip(l1, l2))))
```

Comment: Lose the `pass` :)

Comment: I think this answer strikes the best balance between brevity and comprehensibility. One-liners are possible, but really hard to read.

Comment: @Thomas I agree. Look at updated answer, I would still prefer to use comprehensive approach :D

Comment: *"not-recommended"* — I'd always recommend the smallest amount of code that can get the job done, especially if it's probably more performant than a lot of manual looping with more method calls (though that'd need to be benchmarked to be conclusive). Less code simply holds fewer chances for typos and dumb bugs. If the code becomes somewhat obscure, add comments that explain what it does properly.

Comment: @deceze Roger that.

Comment: Thank you. I think the solution by @Anetropic is great, even if it works only for zeroes. By the way it was what I needed now. Your solution is what I am using now with the only difference that I use if x*y != 0 since I am working with integers.

Answer (score 0):

So I get the index values of the zeros in the 2 lists. Then only keep values not in those index postions.

```
l1 = [0, 1, 3, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]
l2 = [4, 7, 0, 0, 8, 9, 1, 2]


indx1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(l1) if x == 0]
indx2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(l2) if x == 0]

idx = list(set(indx1 + indx2))

nz1 = [j for i, j in enumerate(l1) if i not in idx]
nz2 = [j for i, j in enumerate(l2) if i not in idx]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
l1 = [0, 1, 3, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0]
l2 = [4, 7, 0, 0, 8, 9, 1, 2]

l1C,l2C = zip(*[(x,y) for x, y in zip(l1, l2) if x != 0 and y != 0])

print(l1C)
print(l2C)
```

OUTPUT

```
(1, 6, 8)
(7, 8, 1)
```

Comment: zip(*[(x, y) for x, y in zip(l1, l2) if x * y != 0]) works fine too in my case